# How to join on multiple columns in entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework

How can I join multiple columns with `Data.Entiy Join()`  ?
The table schemas for example:

```
TableA
Id

TableB
Id
TableA_ID1: FK => TableA.Id
TableA_ID2: FK => TableA.Id
```

So I need to be able to join on `TableA_ID1` and `TableA_ID2` since either of these columns could reference `TableA` however I only seem to be able to choose 1 column in the `innerKeySelector` param of `Join()`

Something like this would be ideal where you could use the selector as a tuple but its throwing define type errors

```
db.TableA.
.Join(db.TableB, 
    x => x.Id,
    y => (y.TableA_ID1, y.TableB_ID2),
    (x, y) => new
    {
        //Do something with results
    }).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: First: you shouldn't join A and B by one join. It'll only return records where `A_ID1` and `A_ID2` are equal. Then, in SQL you'd join `TableA` twice, with both ID columns in B, using aliases like a1 and a2. But finally, in Entity Framework LINQ queries you shouldn't join at all (well, hardly ever), but use navigation properties. Entity B should have two reference navigation properties to A.

Answer (score 1):

No need to join. Just use your Navigation Properties and you can traverse both relationships in the query projection.  Eg

```
db.TableB.Select( b => new {b.Id, SomeAId = b.SomeA.Id, OtherAId = b.OtherA.Id,  . . . };
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of `Join` columns must be equal. use this syntax

```
 db.TableA.
.Join(db.TableB,
    x => new { val1 = x.Id, val2 = x.Id },
    y => new { val1 = y.TableA_ID1, val2 = y.TableB_ID2 },
    (x, y) => new
    {
        //Do something with results
    }).ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Seems there's an issue with repeating the `x.Id`: `An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name`

Comment: I edited the answer. You can give each column a nickname

Comment: You still need names on the y anonymous selector. It looks like if I create an extra class to standardize the selector it works and doesn't complain about not being able to recognize the types

Comment: The corresponding columns should have the same name and their data type should be the same, and if one int? Was the corresponding column also an int? Be. I edited the answer.

Comment: They're all the same types, it just looks like it can't distinguish the type of the inner and outer key selectors using anonymous types

Comment: The join isn't correct anyway, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should Join twice, and it looks clearer if you use query syntax:

```
from a in TableA
join b1 in TableB on b1.ID1 equals a.ID
join b2 in TableB on b2.ID2 equals a.ID
select new {
  ... 
}
```